# SAS pass array in SAS macro

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I try to do some calculations based on existing columns and add the results back to the datasets. Could anyone help?

Here is what I try to write in SAS:

```
%macro ColumnCal1(m,prefix);
data _null_;
attr_&prefix. = sum(of &m.1-&m.3);
call symput("attr_&prefix.",attr_&prefix.);
run;
%mend ColumnCal1;

data c2;
set c1;
array mth{12} m1-m12;
%ColumnCal1(m=mth, prefix=ttl);
attr_ttl =&attr_ttl.;  
run;
```

Comment: Share some reproducible example

Comment: If you want to expand your macro inside of a data step it should only generate statements that are valid inside of a data step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood cthe problem you have a dataset and you want to calculate sum of different columns using a macro. I have shared an example below. Try it out.
Suppose you have a dataset with array like this:

```
data have;
array mnth{*} m1-m4;
input mnth{*};
cards;
1 3 6 9
2 4 8 10
;
run;
```

**Code:**
To calculate sum of different columns macro columncal1 is created with parameters
1) Input: Input file which contains the variables
2) Start: First column from which sum needs to be calculated
3) End: Last column till which sum needs to be calculated
4) Prefix: Prefix of the computed column name
5) Output: Output file which gives the result

```
%macro ColumnCal1(input=,start=,end=,prefix=,output=);
data &output.;
set &input.;
attr_&prefix = sum(of &start.-&end.);
run;
%mend ColumnCal1;

%ColumnCal1(input=have,start=m1,end=m2,prefix=ttl,output=want1);   
/* Dataset want1 having all the initial columns plus sum of m1 and m2 stored in a variable attr_ttl has been created from have dataset*/

%ColumnCal1(input=want1,start=m2,end=m3,prefix=ttl1,output=want2);  
/* Dataset want2 having all the initial columns plus sum of m1 and m2 stored in a variable attr_ttl has been created from want1 dataset*/
```

**My Output (want2) :**

```
m1  |m2 |m3 |m4 |attr_ttl |attr_ttl1
1   |3  |6  |9  |4        |9
2   |4  |8  |10 |6        |12
```

If you have any different requirement please do let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked just as you described. But later I found out a better way to implement it by using proc iml.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest data steps. Once SAS sees the new data step starting it stops compiling the first one and runs it. Also how does your current macro know how to find the data since there is no SET statement in the data step? Also you cannot reference a macro variable that has not been created yet. So if you generate a macro variable using then `CALL SYMPUTX()` function you cannot reference its value to modify the code of the current data step since the data steps needs to already have been compiled before the `call symputx()` can execute.

Something like this could work.

```
%macro ColumnCal1(m,prefix);
attr_&prefix. = sum(of &m.1-&m.3);
call symput("attr_&prefix.",attr_&prefix.);
%mend ColumnCal1;

data c2;
  set c1;
%ColumnCal1(m=mth, prefix=ttl);
run;
```

Comment: I am afraid what you suggested does not work. The problem is that SAS marco is more like text replacement. It cannot pass any array variables. I used proc iml to make it work.

Comment: It works for the variable names used in your problem. Macros just generate text. As long as the text generated is valid SAS code then it will work fine.  If you want the macro to generate references to data step arrays then generate the code in that syntax.  So instead of generating a variable list like `M1-M3` generate a series of array references like `M(1) M(2) M(3)`.